# Flash messages before user is authenticated

Tags: node.js, flash, session, express, passport.js

Using Node.js Express, I am having trouble understanding how flash images work when a user is trying to login and the login fails - I want to send a flash message to the front-end. But the thing is flash data appears to be attached to req.session. What I don't understand is that req.session data should not exist across different requests quite simply because the user is not authenticated.

You can see the structure of req.session, and as you can see for some reason the flash messages are piling up, but I can't read them on the front end (I am using EJS).

```
  req.session: Session {
      flash: 
       { loginMessage: [ 'No user found.' ],
         error: 
          [ 'No user found.',
            'Invalid username or password.',
            'Invalid username or password.',
            'Invalid username or password.',
            'No user found.',
            'No user found.',
            'No user found.',
            'No user found.',
            'Invalid username or password.',
            'Invalid username or password.',
```

How can I access these flash messages on the front-end (using EJS for templates)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between a browsing session, and a valid user session. When you use `express-session` a cookie is set on the client. This may or may not include a valid user. You can still set flash messages in the client even when the user has not authenticated, as you have a valid browser session.

`req.session` will be the same for repeated page views, even if the user doesn't log in. You can even track a session between different users logging in.